# scala/spark:Read in RDD[(String,Int)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following text file (previously output from an RDD[(String,Int)] )

```
(ARCHITECTURE,50)
(BUSINESS,17)
(CHEMICAL ENGINEERING,6)
(CHILD DEVELOPMENT,43)
(CIVIL ENGINEERING,26)
 etc
```

I can read in as RDD[String] like this:

```
 spark.sparkContext.textFile(path + s"$path\\${fileName}_labelNames")
```

But  how can I read in as RDD[String,Int]? Is it possible?

EDITED:
Fixed error in RDD type above

Comment: Why not use DataFrame / DataSet? Why can't you just map over the RDD?

Comment: I could, but I was wondering if an RDD can read itself back in. I thought it might be faster and certainly save some coding

Comment: textFile api will read the file line by line as RDD[String], so what you can do is write a step to parse the string lines to expected RDD[String. Int] :) I guess that is what @cricket_007 is suggesting you

Comment: The fact that you wrote into a TextFile instead of a database is exactly why you aren't able to preserve types.

Comment: there are good reasons for that....working with statiisticians on ad hoc analyses

Comment: Alright, well, as the documentation shows, you can always programmatically set the schema on read. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `RDD[String, Int]`, it's illegal.

Maybe what you mean is `RDD[(String, Int)]`.

**Here is how you can transform it from the original data.**

```
val data = original.map { record =>
      val a = record.stripPrefix("(").stripSuffix(")").split(",")
      val k = a(0)
      val v = a(1).toInt
      (k, v)
    }
```

Where original variable is of type `RDD[String]`, as you read from the source.

Comment: yes, that's exact;y what I meant, sorry for misrepresenting